# iOS app breaks on CTFrameDraw

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-text

I am trying to draw a PDF on iOS.

When I draw an attributed string, Xcode always breaks at the line `CTFrameDraw(frameRef, currentContext)` but does not crash nor output any errors. It simply stops until I continue program execution.

Here is my code:

```
private func drawAttributedText(container: Container, text: NSAttributedString, repeated: Bool = false) {
        let currentText = CFAttributedStringCreateCopy(nil, text as CFAttributedStringRef)
        let framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(currentText)
        var currentRange = CFRange(location: 0, length: 0)
        var done = false

        repeat {
            // Get the graphics context.
            let currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

            // Push state
            CGContextSaveGState(currentContext)

            // Put the text matrix into a known state. This ensures
            // that no old scaling factors are left in place.
            CGContextSetTextMatrix(currentContext, CGAffineTransformIdentity)

            let textMaxWidth = pageBounds.width - 2 * pageMargin
            let textMaxHeight: CGFloat = {
                if container.isHeader {
                    return pageBounds.height - headerHeight[container]!
                } else if container.isFooter {
                    return footerMargin
                } else {
                    return pageBounds.height - maxHeaderHeight() - headerSpace - maxFooterHeight() - footerSpace - contentHeight
                }
            }()

            // Create a path object to enclose the text.
            let frame: CGRect = {
                if container.isHeader {
                    return CGRect(x: pageMargin, y: 0, width: textMaxWidth, height: textMaxHeight)
                } else if container.isFooter {
                    return CGRect(x: pageMargin, y: footerHeight[container]!, width: textMaxWidth, height: textMaxHeight)
                } else {
                    return CGRect(x: pageMargin, y: maxFooterHeight() + footerSpace, width: textMaxWidth, height: textMaxHeight)
                }
            }()
            let framePath = UIBezierPath(rect: frame).CGPath

            // Get the frame that will do the rendering.
            // The currentRange variable specifies only the starting point. The framesetter
            // lays out as much text as will fit into the frame.
            let frameRef = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, currentRange, framePath, nil)

            // Core Text draws from the bottom-left corner up, so flip
            // the current transform prior to drawing.
            CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, pageBounds.height)
            CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0)

            // Draw the frame.
            CTFrameDraw(frameRef, currentContext)

            // Pop state
            CGContextRestoreGState(currentContext)

            // Update the current range based on what was drawn.
            let visibleRange = CTFrameGetVisibleStringRange(frameRef)
            currentRange = CFRange(location: visibleRange.location + visibleRange.length , length: 0)

            // Update last drawn frame
            let constraintSize = CGSize(width: textMaxWidth, height: textMaxHeight)
            let drawnSize = CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints(framesetter, visibleRange, nil, constraintSize, nil)

            if container.isHeader {
                headerHeight[container] = headerHeight[container]! + drawnSize.height
            } else if container.isFooter {
                footerHeight[container] = footerHeight[container]! + drawnSize.height
            } else {
                contentHeight += drawnSize.height
            }
            if currentRange.location == CFAttributedStringGetLength(currentText){
                done = true
            } else {
                UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(pageBounds, nil)
                contentHeight = 0

                renderHeaderFooter()
            }
        } while(!done)
    }
```

I am calling this with this attributed text as the parameter:

```
(lldb) po text
Use a premium template if you don't want to see this text!{
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x14808c1a0> font-family: \".SFUIText-Regular\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14.00pt";
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 1, LineSpacing 1, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n    28L,\n    56L,\n    84L,\n    112L,\n    140L,\n    168L,\n    196L,\n    224L,\n    252L,\n    280L,\n    308L,\n    336L\n), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (\n), Lists (\n), BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation NO, HeaderLevel 0";
}
```

The backtrace:

```
    * thread #16: tid = 0x2ee74, 0x0000000180e2e7d4 libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_throw, queue = 'com.apple.root.background-qos', stop reason = breakpoint 2.2
    frame #0: 0x0000000180e2e7d4 libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_throw
    frame #1: 0x0000000183ce2e24 libFontParser.dylib`TcmapEncodingTable::GetSubtable(unsigned short, unsigned short, unsigned short, unsigned short*) + 528
    frame #2: 0x0000000183cf3fcc libFontParser.dylib`TcmapEncodingTable::TcmapEncodingTable(TSFNTFont const&, unsigned short, unsigned short, unsigned short) + 116
    frame #3: 0x0000000183cf3e3c libFontParser.dylib`TTrueTypeFont::GetCJKScript() const + 292
    frame #4: 0x0000000183cf3bc8 libFontParser.dylib`TTrueTypeFont::GetRegistryOrderingSupplement(TStringRef&, TStringRef&, int&) const + 76
    frame #5: 0x0000000183cf3a70 libFontParser.dylib`FPFontCopyRegistryOrderingSupplement + 80
    frame #6: 0x0000000183cf3944 libFontParser.dylib`FPGetFontSubsetFormat + 448
    frame #7: 0x0000000182c7308c CoreGraphics`PDFFont::create(FontSet const&, CGFont*, int) + 92
    frame #8: 0x0000000182b47fe4 CoreGraphics`FontSet::add_font(CGFont*) + 96
    frame #9: 0x0000000182d3296c CoreGraphics`PDFContentStreamDrawGlyphs + 868
    frame #10: 0x0000000182cbd740 CoreGraphics`pdf_DrawGlyphs + 272
    frame #11: 0x0000000182addbcc CoreGraphics`rips_DrawGlyphs + 196
    frame #12: 0x0000000182cf3a20 CoreGraphics`draw_glyphs + 656
    frame #13: 0x0000000183e8f2b4 CoreText`DrawSbixGlyphsAtPositions(TFont const*, __CFData const*, unsigned short const*, CGPoint const*, unsigned long, CGContext*, CGAffineTransform, CGAffineTransform) + 1644
    frame #14: 0x0000000183e38008 CoreText`CTFontDrawGlyphsWithAdvances + 552
    frame #15: 0x0000000183e47874 CoreText`TRun::DrawGlyphs(CGContext*, CFRange) const + 556
    frame #16: 0x0000000183e82a94 CoreText`TFrame::DrawFrame(CGContext*) const + 616
  * frame #17: 0x0000000101bda690 TPPDF`PDFGenerator.(container=ContentLeft, text=0x0000000125cbcf70, repeated=false, self=0x0000000125cd9ec0)(Container, text : NSAttributedString, repeated : Bool) -> () + 1112 at PDFGenerator.swift:216
    frame #18: 0x0000000101bdf4b0 TPPDF`PDFGenerator.(container=ContentLeft, command=AddAttributedText, self=0x0000000125cd9ec0)(Container, command : Command) -> () + 840 at PDFGenerator.swift:485
    frame #19: 0x0000000101bd9be4 TPPDF`PDFGenerator.generatePDFdata(progress=0x000000010010ba00 MCB`partial apply forwarder for reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned (@unowned CoreGraphics.CGFloat) -> (@unowned ()) to @callee_owned (@in CoreGraphics.CGFloat) -> (@out ()) at MCBSimplePDFFactory.swift, self=0x0000000125cd9ec0) -> ()?) -> NSData + 2524 at PDFGenerator.swift:131
    frame #20: 0x000000010010b73c MCB`MCBSimplePDFFactory.createPDF(document=0x0000000125ceb0a0, progress=0x00000001001c3304 MCB`partial apply forwarder for reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned (@unowned CoreGraphics.CGFloat) -> (@unowned ()) to @callee_owned (@in CoreGraphics.CGFloat) -> (@out ()) at MCBPDFGenerator.swift, self=0x00000001246215b0) -> ()?) -> NSData + 14288 at MCBSimplePDFFactory.swift:159
    frame #21: 0x00000001001c37bc MCB`MCBPDFGenerator.(progress=0x00000001001518b8 MCB`partial apply forwarder for reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned (@unowned Swift.Double) -> (@unowned ()) to @callee_owned (@in (progress : Swift.Double)) -> (@out ()) at MCBPDFExportViewController.swift, template=Simple, document=0x0000000125ceb0a0, self=0x0000000125c7a100, completion=0x00000001001517b0 MCB`partial apply forwarder for MCB.MCBPDFExportViewController.(createPDF (MCB.MCBPDFTemplate) -> ()).(closure #1) at MCBPDFExportViewController.swift) -> (), (progress : Double) -> ()?) -> ()).(closure #1) + 464 at MCBPDFGenerator.swift:80
    frame #22: 0x000000010010348c MCB`thunk + 44 at MCBDocumentIngridientCell.swift:0
    frame #23: 0x0000000102395a7c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
    frame #24: 0x0000000102395a3c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 16
    frame #25: 0x00000001023a4c9c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_root_queue_drain + 2344
    frame #26: 0x00000001023a4364 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_worker_thread3 + 132
    frame #27: 0x0000000181439470 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 1092
    frame #28: 0x0000000181439020 libsystem_pthread.dylib`start_wqthread + 4
```

Can somebody please help me how to understand the issue and how I should continue debugging/resolving it?

Comment: This seems like a CoreGraphics bug.  I'm getting a very similar crash attempting to use `UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter` to convert HTML to PDF or to just print it.  There's a thread on it here: http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2016/Apr/msg00108.html

Comment: I wish I'd payed more attention to your post.  I accidentally had the 'All Exceptions' breakpoint set.  Continuing execution works.  I saw other posts that suggested C++ exceptions like this can be expected parts of normal flow.